# Is there any way to read system hive files within a booted system?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-registry

Is there any way to get a copy of `%systemroot%\system32\config\system`, once the system is up and running? I know the OS puts a lock on this file to keep it from getting trashed, but all I need is to be able to read it, long enough to grab a copy. Perhaps something in the 'native API' would do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're unable to copy that file is not a permission issue, or Windows being "protective" about the file; the problem is, that file is always in use (and therefore locked) on a running system.

When loaded, the file is mapped to `HKLM\System`; you can use `reg.exe` to export its contents, both in text and binary format:

```
reg export HKLM\System system.reg
reg save HKML\System system.hiv
```

The first one can be opened using any text editor; the latter is a full binary dump, and can be opened by loading it in REGEDIT.

Also, be aware that certain subkeys of HKLM\System are *not* stored on disk, but are rather populated at runtime by the OS (the most notorious one is `CurrentControlSet`); so, dumping/saving them might make no sense at all.

Comment: Ok, so windows puts a lock on the file. I *know* there's a lock on the file. What purpose does this lock serve other than to protect the file from corruption by other processes?

Comment: @justjeff Re-read this answer, it explains *why* the actual file locked -- it's actively *in use* by the OS.

Comment: So is what you're trying to say here, and not saying explicitly, is that there is so much ongoing change in the file (as a result of windows using it), that there's no meaningful snapshot that can be taken of it?

Comment: @JustJeff If you need a place-in-time copy, PXE (or live CD/DVD) boot the computer, and grab the file.

Comment: Writes to the system hive are infrequent.  I'm not sure whether the reg save command (or the equivalent API function) generates a snapshot in the strict sense, but it is certainly a usable copy under normal circumstances.  If you'll tell us why you want the copy we may be able to advise you better.

Comment: In regards to your other question: in Unix, opening a file does not lock it by default, and the programmer needs to take extra steps to lock it if they want to.  In Windows, opening a file locks it by default, and the programmer needs to take extra steps if they want it to remain unlocked.  Now, it's trivial to open a file and leave it unlocked, but few people bother unless there's a specific reason to do so.  So the system hive may just be locked by default, there doesn't need to be a purpose for the lock per se.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the [Volume Shadow Copy Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

On a server platform, the [Diskshadow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx) command-line interface is available.

Comment: NB: Massimo's answer (using reg save) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need a copy that's right up to date it can sometimes be simpler to just restore the file from backup to a different location.